# How to enable compression with mod_deflate

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-deflate

Page speed insights tells me to enable compression for google-maps source.
It recommends to use `mod_deflate` if using Apache.
Well, I've put the next snippet code inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I've enabled `mod_deflate` (and automatically enables `mod_filter`), and `mod_headers` and `mod_mime` were already enabled..
But Page speed page still tells me to enable compression. What am I doing wrong, or what should I do?

This is a screen shot of page speed error:

[image: Page speed's screen shot]

Comment: can you please update question with screenshot from PageSpeed?
I don't see any problems with your configuration. I've got similar and Google is reporting green status in my case.

Comment: I need 1 reputation's point to attach images.

Comment: try again... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are third party resources, and you have no control over whether they use compression or not (they will not, because doing so would potentially expose private data in a [BREACH or CRIME attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_%28security_exploit%29)). You can safely ignore messages suggesting compression of resources loaded from third party sites, and messages suggesting compression of content served via HTTPS.